# Ember.js upgrade from version 1 to 2 mandatory?

Tags: ember.js

We have an web application which uses ember.js version 1.11.3. Can we safely stay on this version, or is an upgrade to the latest ember.js version kind of mandatory (for security or maintanability reasons)?

Comment: This depends on what level of security concerns your company has. I'd recommend you have a look at the release notes and guides for upgrading and the 2.0 release post https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2015/08/13/ember-2-0-released.html

Answer (score 2):

From a security / maintenance point of view, Ember 1.11 hasn't been supported for a long time. Ember 1.13 was an LTS release with longer security support, but it too is no longer maintained. So yes, it would be wise to upgrade (and you will start seeing your app run faster and get smaller once you are past Ember 2.10)